# Navigate to external url from LWC (iframe)

Tags: lightning-web-components, iframe, redirect, js

Pretty new to LWC

I have a site that I wrote with LWC: VF page -> Aura -> LWC.

This site is a form that is used on an external web page.

I'm trying after submitting the form, to navigate the parent page to a different URL (in the same origin that the external web page is).

I think that using the NavigationMixin.Navigate is not helpful unless there is a param that indicates it's a parent window - which I didn't found.

I also tried to use

```
   window.top.location ="https://externalSite.com";
```

But nothing happens - not even an error.

The External Web Page have this line of HTML to iframe my site in it :

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; min-height: 780px" src="https://abcd-site.cs84.force.com/myForm"> ></iframe>
```

How can I achieve this?

Many thanks,

My code:

HTML:

```
<template>
  <div >
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick={submitRegAction}></lightning-button>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
submitRegAction(){
       
    createAccountInDBMap({gg: JSON.stringify(this.mapValueToCLS)}).then(result => {
        window.top.location ="https://externalSite.com/";

        // this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        //     type:"standard__webPage",
        //     attributes: {
        //         url: 'https://externalSite.com/'
        //     }
        // })
  
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error is ', error);
    })


}
```